# Cannot login locally on a NFS attached linux server after a NFS hang

Tags: linux, rhel, mount, nfs

I set up a **NFS server** for a cluster node and i used it for a while.
One day my nodes were unable to mount so i had to reboot the system.
Since, it takes a long time to boot and i'm **unable to login** on the nodes with any account credentials.

During the boot it gives me this **"FS-Cache: Duplicate cookie detected"** error.

Here are the error logs, it seems to be related to **pam authentication** but i don't know where to look: [image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that your file system is full. Do you have the possibility to login as root? Because  normally for root is some space reserved to ensure he can still login and clear things up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still had plenty of disk space,and i couldn't login as root.

Comment: Sorry, but was worth a try.